# How to iterate over part of a hash in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, hash, iterator

```
h = Hash.new
(1..100).each { |v| h.store(v * 2, v*v) }
```

What is the best way to iterate over a given part of the hash without using the keys? For example, from element 10 to element 20? Using Ruby 1.9.3.

EDIT - In response to Dave's comment:
Originally I wanted to access the data through keys (hence the hash). But I also want to iterate by element number. BTW, each element is a hash.

So, what is the best way to design a hash of hashes or array of hashes that can be iterated by  element number or accessed by key? The data looks like the following. There are missing dates.

6/23/2011 -> 5, 6, 8, 3, 6
6/26/2011 -> 6, 8, 4, 8, 5
6/27/2011 -> 8, 4, 3, 2, 7

Comment: What's the usecase? Knowing what you're trying to do may affect the answer.

Comment: What do you mean "accessed by key"? That's how you normally access a hash value.

Comment: I mean "accessed by key" is h[6/23/2011].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand what you're asking for, you can iterate over a portion of your hash as follows.  This gives you the 1001st through 2000th values:

```
h.keys[1000..1999].each do |key|
    # Do something with h[key]
end
```

Comment: This is useful, but is it better than using an array? If each key is an integer then it is a hash masquerading as an array...unless I am missing something.

Comment: @BSeven I was assuming you were using the Hash as discussed in your other question and at the bottom of this question (with the dates as keys). In which case a Hash is definitely *much* better than an Array. Even when the keys are all integers, it's not "a Hash masquerading as an Array" unless the keys start at 0 and increment by 1, or something easily converted to/from that.

Comment: Ooooohhhh, I didn't understand that you can iterate over the hash using integers even if the keys are something completely different. Cool. It's the best of both worlds.

Comment: @BSeven Yeah, the `Hash.keys()` method gives you an Array of the keys, which in Ruby 1.9+ maintain insertion order. Subscripting that Array with a Range gives you whichever portion of the keys you want, which you can then use to access that portion of the Hash.

Answer (score 1):

I think you better use Array for that (Hash in Ruby 1.9.3 are ordered but the access method is the keys). So:

```
a = h.values
# or
a = h.to_a
```

Comment: I think you mean hashes are *ordered* rather than sorted.

Answer (score 1):

Convert it to an array, then [slice](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-5B-5D) it:

```
h.to_a[10..20].each { |k, v| do_stuff }
```

Note that before Ruby 1.9, the order of elements in a hash are not guaranteed, so this will not necessarily work as you expect.

Alternatively, you could use `each_with_index` and skip over the unwanted elements:

```
h.each_with_index do |(k, v), i|
  next unless (10..20).include?(i)
  # do stuff
end
```

Comment: That was my first idea, but I didn't know if `Hash.to_s` is a slow operation. Does it iterate over the hash to convert it?

Comment: @BSeven Yes, because it has to create a whole new data structure (the array). I've added an alternative solution that doesn't create a new data structure, but still has to iterate over it. Hashes aren't really indexed in this way, so what you're trying to do isn't very natural to code for a hash.

Comment: The hash may have 10,000 elements, so converting to array isn't such a great idea...

Comment: There comes a point that a database is a good answer. With 10K elements, you might be at that point. Also, a DBM has lots of ways to retrieving the data, either sequentially or randomly. It'll take a bit more to set up, but there are times they can't be beat.

Comment: @the Tin Man Actually, PostgreSQL and MySQL are already set up on this machine. But it's not a Rails app. What is the easiest way to integrate the database into a Ruby app?

Comment: Look at the [Sequel](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/documentation.html) gem. It's a great way to connect to databases, and lets you choose whether it should act as a DBI or an ORM. Highly recommended. If you already have ActiveRecord experience, you can use it without Rails, but I still prefer Sequel.

Comment: @theTinMan Cool. Why do you prefer Sequel over ActiveRecord? Is it better in some ways?

Answer (score 1):

```
h = Hash.new
(1..100).each { |v| h.store(v * 2, v*v) }

#for an array of arrays
h.drop(9).take(10) #plus an optional block
#if the slice must be a hash:
slice = Hash[h.drop(9).take(10)]
```

But if this is an often repeating operation you might be better off using a database.