# How to set up data structure for efficient search in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash, ruby-1.9.3

I have an array of hashes. Each hash looks like:

```
'date'=>6/23/2011, value1=>6, value2=>8, value3=>3, value4=>6
```

The array has about 10,000 hash elements.

Is there a built-in way in Ruby to ***efficiently*** find by the index of an element by date? I know there is `Array.index` but does it iterate through the array sequentially?

Is there a better way to set up my data so that it can be accessed efficiently?

Ruby 1.9.3

Comment: Any time you say "array" you lose searching speed, either because you have to do a sort before you search, or you have to do a sequential search. Think about using hashes any time you want to do a lookup.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It sounds like you're doing it backwards.  You should have a hash of arrays:

```
{'6/23/2011' => [6, 8, 3, 6]}
```

That way, given a date, you have constant-time access to the corresponding data.  It also gives you cleaner access to the values, rather than the clumsy 'valueX' stuff.

Comment: An hash of hashes might also work - I suspect that `value*` are placeholders for more meaningful names.

Comment: According to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169791/how-to-iterate-over-part-of-a-hash-in-ruby), that's what OP is using right now.

Comment: Exactly. Originally I was using a hash (of arrays), but I  want to iterate over the data by element number. For example, elements 1,000 to 2,000. Is there an elegant solution in Ruby?

Comment: @IdanArye Yes, I used value* to simplify the question.

Comment: @BSeven Yes, you can elegantly iterate over a portion of a Hash.  See my answer to your other question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11173620/1427098